# Explain Numerically The Following

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic, quadratic-residues, numerical-calculus

This question is one of the unsolved problems in my Encryption and Cipher Systems subject:

For prime $p>2$ and $0<a<p\,;$

$
a^{(p-1)/2}(mod \,p)=
\begin{cases}
1;\ \ \ \ if \ \ \ \, a\in R_{2}\\
p-1;\ \ \ \ \text{otherwise}\\
\end{cases}
$

where $R_{2}$ denotes the set of quadratic residues modulo $p$ that is, there exists $x$ such that :
$x^{2} \equiv a \, mod \,p$

I really don't understand what it does mean by the term “Numerically “ also i don’t know how and where to start to write a proof of such problem, So i haven’t tried anything. Any help will be appreciated and thanks a lot

Comment: You posted a similar question earlier.

Comment: You posted [the same question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3736922/409) a couple of hours ago. Re-posting is not the way to attract attention (nor to escape down- and close-votes). Rather, you could/should edit that question to perhaps address comments you have received to improve its quality.  (Voting to close as duplicate.)

Answer (score 2):

Well, let's make an abstract algebric approach.
Let A the group quotient with prime $p$. And let $a$ be element of A/{0,1}
As U(p) is generator of A, we know:
$$a^{p-1}=1=e$$ where e is element neutre multiplicatif.
with $p-1$ is the smallest number which satistifies that equation.
Which also means: for all integer $a>1$ and $p$ prime we have:

$(1)$ $$a^{p-1}=1\left(mod\:p\right)$$

if   $a∈R_2$ (1) holds. For second case let's assume that there is $a$ integer $m<p$ such that:

$(2)$
$$a^{^{\frac{\left(p-1\right)}{2}}}=m\left(mod\:p\right)$$

Square both sides:
$$a^{\left(p-1\right)}=m^2\left(mod\:p\right)$$
By (1) we have
$m^2=1$ so $m=1$ or $m=-1$
By (1) $m$ cannot be $1$ because $p-1$ is smallest number which satisfies equation. If $m=1$ we
get (2) satisfies same equation with $\frac{\left(p-1\right)}{2}$.

Finally we get $m=-1$

Comment: i couldn't find on mathtype but 1 has a bar on it on first equation